# Showing that the matrices are invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove that $A^3B^3C^3$ and $A^TBC^T$ are invertible given that A, B, and C are all square, same size and invertible. For the second one, I started out:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTrnv.jpg)

I think I did the proof right, but I am not sure if I showed that these satisfied the required properties of invertible matrix. I will greatly appreciate if you have any advice!

Comment: Can you use determinants?

Comment: I think you have done the right things. Just take care in the order of your proof - writing (A^3B^3C^3)^-1 in the first line suggests that it is necessarily invertible, which is what you are showing!

Comment: Consider what you have done good rough work. Now for the proof, start by multiplying A^3B^3C^3 by what you claim is its inverse. If you do this on both sides and get the identity, then it is indeed the inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your work seems fine,

$$(A^3B^3C^3)^{-1}=C^{-3}B^{-3}A^{-3}=(C^{-1})^3(B^{-1})^3(A^{-1})^3,$$ 
and since $A,$ $B,$ and $C,$ are invertible, then we have the desired result.

Similarly, $(AA^{-1})^T = (A^{-1})^TA^T=I_n.$ Since $I_n^T=I_n.$ Then we have

$$(A^TBC^T)^{-1}=(C^T)^{-1}B^{-1}(A^T)^{-1}$$ is a product of invertible matrices, and is therefore invertible.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use determinant:

$$\det (A^3B^3C^3)= \det(A)^3\det(B)^3\det (C)^3\ne 0$$ so $A^3B^3C^3$ is invertibile. Similar for the other, just remeber that $\det (A^T)=\det (A)$.

Comment: While this proof is nice, have they necessarily covered determinants? Some argue that determinants should not be introduced until the very end of a first course in linear algebra.

Comment: Which does make inverting matrices rather more tedious!

Comment: I agree with @bounceback, although this is how I would prove this statement if left to my own assumptions.

Comment: @bounceback, you must be familiar with Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, and his determiRant http://www.axler.net/DwD.html

Comment: @Chickenmancer Guilty as charged! I also enjoy Sergei Treil's 'Linear Algebra Done Wrong', although neither is much use at graduate level

Comment: True. I think any student should be acquainted with both texts and approaches. Computational tools are as necessary as elegant proofs which avoid them.